# Sonarqube scan from Jenkins : ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jgit.api.Git

Tags: java, git, maven, jenkins, sonarqube

I have a problem when doing a SonarQube Scan from Jenkins. See the stacktrace in debug mode :

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar (default-cli) on project scbm-order-parent: Unable to register extension org.sonarsource.scm.git.JGitBlameCommand from plugin 'scmgit': org/eclipse/jgit/api/Git: org.eclipse.jgit.api.Git -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar (default-cli) on project scbm-order-parent: Unable to register extension org.sonarsource.scm.git.JGitBlameCommand from plugin 'scmgit'
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:347)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:582)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Unable to register extension org.sonarsource.scm.git.JGitBlameCommand from plugin 'scmgit'
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ExceptionHandling.handle(ExceptionHandling.java:36)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ScannerBootstrapper.execute(ScannerBootstrapper.java:81)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.SonarQubeMojo.execute(SonarQubeMojo.java:122)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to register extension org.sonarsource.scm.git.JGitBlameCommand from plugin 'scmgit'
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.addExtension(ComponentContainer.java:249)
    at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.ExtensionInstaller.doInstall(ExtensionInstaller.java:76)
    at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.ExtensionInstaller.install(ExtensionInstaller.java:57)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.addBatchExtensions(ProjectScanContainer.java:227)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doBeforeStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:115)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:141)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:128)
    at org.sonar.scanner.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:47)
    at org.sonar.scanner.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:86)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:143)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:128)
    at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:118)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:117)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy31.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:233)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedScanner.java:151)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ScannerBootstrapper.execute(ScannerBootstrapper.java:78)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jgit/api/Git
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AdaptingInjection$1.run(AdaptingInjection.java:203)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AdaptingInjection.injectionMethodAnnotated(AdaptingInjection.java:200)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AdaptingInjection.methodAnnotatedInjectionAdapter(AdaptingInjection.java:171)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AdaptingInjection.createComponentAdapter(AdaptingInjection.java:70)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehaviorFactory.createComponentAdapter(AbstractBehaviorFactory.java:44)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.OptInCaching.createComponentAdapter(OptInCaching.java:45)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.addComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:536)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.access$300(DefaultPicoContainer.java:84)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer$AsPropertiesPicoContainer.addComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1149)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.addExtension(ComponentContainer.java:247)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jgit.api.Git
    at org.sonar.classloader.ParentFirstStrategy.loadClass(ParentFirstStrategy.java:39)
    at org.sonar.classloader.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:87)
    at org.sonar.classloader.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:76)
    ... 58 more
```

Used versions :

- Jenkins 1.624 (ok... old one but cannot upgrade it now)
- sources scan with Java 8
- Sonarqube 6.3 (Git plugin version 1.2, java plugin version 4.6.0.8784)

Extract from the pom.xml :

```
<pluginManagement>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2</version>
                </plugin>
</pluginManagement>
```

mvn command line :

```
clean install -U -X org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar -Dsonar.host.url=http://x.x.x.x:9000 -Dsonar.working.directory=/tmp/.sonar/ -Dsonar.login=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx -DskipTests=true site
```

Any idea ?

I have also tried to add the JGit artifact in the plugin management part in my pom.xml, without success... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it works now. Just disable **Git SCM plugin**. Don't know why...
Then disable **Sonar XML Plugin** because of the next error :

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sonar.squidbridge.api.AnalysisException
```

If anyone know why, please answer :)

I have also seen that some guys have updated JGit dependency version in Sonar Git plugin : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sonarqube/TcRrB9XBk8o.
Not tested...

Answer (score 1):

We ran into a similar issue with Sonarqube v5.6.7. The root cause appears to have been that the local cache of the plugin library that gets downloaded by the sonar scanner was corrupted.

Content found under "/logs/ssc/sonar/cache/cache":

```
./675ef60911b1d93e17e84ab20261e18a
./675ef60911b1d93e17e84ab20261e18a/sonar-xml-plugin-1.5-SNAPSHOT.jar_unzip
./675ef60911b1d93e17e84ab20261e18a/sonar-xml-plugin-1.5-SNAPSHOT.jar_unzip/META-INF
./675ef60911b1d93e17e84ab20261e18a/sonar-xml-plugin-1.5-SNAPSHOT.jar_unzip/META-INF/lib
```

Note that the "lib" dir was empty. Deleting the entire content of the "/logs/ssc/sonar/cache/cache" cache directory and running another project scan caused it to re-download and the lib dir was now populated with the list of dependency libraries for that plugin.

To find where the local cache of plugin jars lived I ran "strace -f -e trace=open,close,read,write -o strace.log " and then searched "strace.log" for a plugin name.